# How dou you write/call 2 tables in $this->db->table('table_name') in Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter-4

Hello i have 2 tables that i want to call right now, for the EDIT (part of the CRUD)
tables:

1. table_a
2. table_b

i found in youtube how to update/edit from 2 tables, i need to call bot of the tables.
here's the code for the model

```
  public function  edit_this($ID_A)
{
    return $this->db->table('table_a', '*i don't know how to insert the 2nd table')->where('ID_A', $ID_A)->get()->getRowArray();

}
```

Here's the controller

```
 public function this_edit($ID_A)
    {
        $data = [
            'title' => 'Admin',
            'navbartitel' => 'You know this',
            'alledit' => $this->theModel->edit_this($ID_A),
            'validation' => \Config\Services::validation()
        ];
        return view('this/all/edit', $data);
    }
```

it works but i only can accsess the tabel_a, but i need them both so i can show what i've written in the edit form, from the database

anyone can help? thank you

Answer (score 0):

`$this->db->table(...)` returns an instance of QueryBuilder and will happily accept a **single** string of comma-separated tables (`"table1, table2..."`), or even an array for that matter (`['table1', 'table2'...]`), as its first parameter. You are doing neither and instead passing multiple parameters.

When you call `table()`, the value passed in the first parameter is used during the creation of the database-specific Builder class:

```
public function table($tableName)
{
    if (empty($tableName))
    {
        throw new DatabaseException('You must set the database table to be used with your query.');
    }

    $className = str_replace('Connection', 'Builder', get_class($this));

    return new $className($tableName, $this);
}
```

The DB-specific Builder class has no constructor of its own so falls back on the `__construct` defined in BaseBuilder, which it extends:

```
public function __construct($tableName, ConnectionInterface &$db, array $options = null)
{
    if (empty($tableName))
    {
        throw new DatabaseException('A table must be specified when creating a new Query Builder.');
    }

    $this->db = $db;

    $this->from($tableName);

...
```

I've truncated this for brevity because the important part is that call to `$this->from`, which is in the end how multiple tables get processed:

```
public function from($from, bool $overwrite = false)
{
    if ($overwrite === true)
    {
        $this->QBFrom = [];
        $this->db->setAliasedTables([]);
    }

    foreach ((array) $from as $val)
    {
        if (strpos($val, ',') !== false)
        {
            foreach (explode(',', $val) as $v)
            {
                $v = trim($v);
                $this->trackAliases($v);

                $this->QBFrom[] = $v = $this->db->protectIdentifiers($v, true, null, false);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $val = trim($val);

            // Extract any aliases that might exist. We use this information
            // in the protectIdentifiers to know whether to add a table prefix
            $this->trackAliases($val);

            $this->QBFrom[] = $this->db->protectIdentifiers($val, true, null, false);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```